# For-loop and DateTime Problem

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm trying to make use `for` on a `DateTime` like this:

```
for (DateTime d = _BookedCheckIn; d <= _BookedCheckOut; d.AddDays(1))
{
    // ...
}
```

But the problem is that `d` does not increase. Does anyone have an idea of what the problem is?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use:

```
for (DateTime d = _BookedCheckIn; d <= _BookedCheckOut; d = d.AddDays(1))
{
```

When you call `d.AddDays`, it's returning a *new* DateTime, not changing the one you already created.

Answer (score 7):

d.AddDays(1) does not actually add a day to d. It returns a *new datetime object* 1 day larger than d.

This problem has been documented here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380819/common-programming-mistakes-for-net-developers-to-avoid/1213588#1213588

Answer (score 2):

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of days to the
>   value of this instance.
>
> This method does not change the value of this DateTime. Instead, it
>   returns a new DateTime whose value is the result of this operation.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

So... It should be as below

```
for (DateTime d = _BookedCheckIn; d <= _BookedCheckOut; d = d.AddDays(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively

```
d += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```